# Error connecting to SQL Server through Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database through Oracle SQL Developer (version 4.2), after adding 3rd part JTDS jar 1.3 version.

After adding the connection details under the SQL Server tab, I am getting this error while retrieving database:

> Error: the target database is in an availability group and is currently accessible for connections when application intent is set to read only.

Where and how to add application intent?

I am unable to see any advanced connection properties button which are there in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio in  which I am able to connect via setting `applicationintent=readonly`.

Thanks.

Comment: No idea, I have never used MS SQL Server, but - it probably wouldn't hurt if you installed the latest (20.x) SQL Developer version.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting the AG listener name rather than a specific server name.

Comment: Dan, I am able to connect to server through SQL server management studio via providing the IP and adding applicationintent=readonly in additional parameters.  I am not sure about ag listener name.